# Increment/Decrement for Vector Iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

Nicolai Josuttis's "The C++ Standard Library"

Chapter 9: STL Iterator states:

Following might not compile on some platform:

```
std::vector <int> coll;

//sort, starting with second element
//- NONPORTABLE version

if (coll.size() > 1){
   std::sort(++coll.begin(),col.end());
}
```

> Depending on the platform, the compilation of ++col.begin() might
>   fail. However, if you use for example, a deque rather than a vector,
>   the compilation always succeeds.
>   ... 
>   ...  utility function next() and prev() are provided with C++11 to
>   account for code portability.

Can someone please explain this behavior ?

I got correct output for following with MINGW gcc 4.6.1, Windows OS:

```
std::vector<int> coll ;
for (int i=15; i>=1; i--)
 coll.push_back(i); 

sort(++coll.begin(),coll.end());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this potential issue is explained quite well by Josuttis:

> The reason for this strange problem lies in the fact that iterators of vectors, `array`s, and strings might be implemented as ordinary pointers. And for all fundamental data types, such as pointers, you are not allowed to modify temporary values. For structures and classes, however, doing so is allowed.

In other words, it all depends whether `std::vector<int>::iterator` is defined as a class or is simply a `typedef` for an `int*`. Either is allowed by the standard which is why it may cause an issue on some compilers but not others.

When you call `coll.begin()` a rvalue `std::vector<int>::iterator` is created. If `std::vector<int>::iterator` is a class with an implemented prefix `operator++` then modification of the rvalue is permitted and so it will compile. However, it `std::vector<int>::iterator` is a typedef for a pointer to an int, it is an rvalue of a fundamental type and thus may not compile.

Comment: I'd say it's not only a problem of pointers, but of prvalues. As far as I can see, the iterator requirements for increment are specified for an iterator lvalue (namely `X&` where `X` is the iterator type), and do not apply to prvalues (the return type of `.begin()` is a prvalue).

Answer (score 1):

Josuttis is technically wrong about `++container.begin()` always being defined behavior when `container` is `std::deque`: the standard does not guarantee that `container.begin()` returns a modifiable lvalue for *any* container type. When he says "always succeeds" what he really means is "on every implementation I know, it succeeds" which isn't exactly the same thing.

In fairness, before C++11 it was impossible for a non-`const` object of class type to restrict its operations to lvalues, but don't be surprised if you start seeing classes in the near future which don't allow assignment, increment, and decrement on rvalues for consistency with fundamental types.

Answer (score 0):

You can do `++` on the return value of `vector::begin()` if it returns an l-value - essentially an object type which has an overloaded `++ operator`. I don't think the standard insists that is how `vector::iterator` should be implemented. A compliant C++ standard library may implement `vector::iterator` as a pointer - i.e. for `vector<T>`, `vector<T>::iterator` may be `T*`, in which case the ++ operation will not compile because the return is a r-value and you cannot increment a r-value.

The C++ library you are using currently implements `vector::iterator` as an object with an overloaded `++` & hence it works. But that doesn't mean it's portable.

Try this program

```
class iter
{
    int * p_;

    public:
    iter(int * p):p_(p) {}

    iter & operator ++()
    {
        ++p_;
        return *this;
    }
};
class A
{
    int * p_;

    public:
    typedef int * iterator;
    typedef iter miterator;

    iterator get()
    {
        return p_;
    }

    miterator ret()
    {
        return miterator(p_);
    }

};


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    A a;

    ++a.get(); // Doesn't compile

    A::iterator i = a.get();
    ++i; // compiles

    ++a.ret(); //compiles
}
```